# Row clicked changes content depending on sql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a dashboard with many components, one of the components is a table. Once the dashboard is loaded only the table is seen, the user should click on one row to see the corresponding information and graphs.

I'm doing this using php and mysql. Can someone help me with implementing this.

I do not want the page to reload, it should be automatically, if the user clicks on a row, the corresponding data changes.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php 
      $sql = "select * from file WHERE id ='".$id."'";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);

      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$row['age']."</td>";
              echo "<tr>";
          }
      }

     ?>

    </tbody>                                
    </table>
```

Comment: Pro tip: Beginners are welcome, but we expect a certain amount of effort to be expended on a question prior to a question being posted. 
We dont write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Comment: I don't need you to write the code for me nor I am a beginner, I'm looking for the concept of how to do it, "help" like you said and not code so please may you help me since you seem like an expert in php and such. @RiggsFolly

Comment: Oh, Ok, then you need to start by researching AJAX, a javascript based concept. This is what you will need to use to make the page contents change without doing a normal round trip to the server for complete new page

Comment: can you elaborate more, like do I save the result and then show it or how exactly?

Comment: Like I said **you** need to do some research on how to code/use AJAX. It is far to big a subject to cover in a simple answer and would be more like a tutorial, and SO is not a tutorial site

Comment: I suggest you also look a the jQuery javascript framework, as this makes the javascript coding 10 times easier for us developers

Answer (score 1):

for interact with server-side without reloading the page you need to use "ajax" and in the server you need to create web service (restful-API service).

also, you can fetch whole data from the server in page load time and show them to the user using jquery or some other UI handling libraries. but in this approach, you must be aware of the size of data. when this data is huge this creates a performance issue for your website.